# License requirements for SSIS on VMRole in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

We are running integration services (SSIS) on a VMRole on Azure. I understand the Win 2008 OS license requirements but can someone shed light on the license requirements for using SSIS in a VM Role? Do we need to obtain a production lic for SQL server? IF that is the case doesnt that defeat the cloud utility model?

Any insight is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on the licensing strategies of Microsoft, but SSIS is not a supported product under Azure special licensing.  Only Windows Server "Azure edition" if you will is included in the cost of an Azure VM.  And obviously, SQL Server license of SQL Azure is included in the price of SQL Azure.  Nothing about external to the cloud-based Azure ecosystem SSIS is covered, afaik.